# Does facebook allow login on any unknown domain policywise?

Tags: facebook, cross-domain, policy

I am thinking of distributing a Flash game that can inject Facebook JS into any webpage that will host it (many free Flash game portals). I can `window.open` Facebook login dialog when the host page sets `allowScriptAccess`.

One of my ideas how to workaround the crossdomain login issue (how to get accessToken back to my Flash game hosted on unknown domain, without fighting cross domain JS and all those browser issues)

1. Flash generates unique token (*tag*)
2. Flash opens comet connection with the *tag* to our server
3. Flash opens OAUTH dialog, forwarding *tag* in `redirect_uri` to allowed
   domain
4. User signs in with Facebook credentials and is redirected to
   `redirect_uri` with active *accessToken* (CODE) and *tag*
5. Facebook redirects to our server passing *accessToken*
6. Our server grabs CODE and *tag* from GET params and extracts *accessToken*
7. Our server forwards *accessToken* to Flash by comet recognized by the
   *tag*
8. Finally - Flash can use facebook features with valid *accessToken*

As I am not a lawyer and those facebook policy docs are not understandable to me...

**Question:** Would facebook allow this kind of login on any domain? I feel I would be working around some security this way.

Comment: Which features are you planning to use? Features without user login will not require this I believe.

Comment: @Kuzgun I am using it to get facebookID to login (it's a multiplayer game) and for publishing opengraph stories + scores (thanks for fixing my typos:)

Comment: If you use OAuth and user signs in, why do you need that token changing? Cant you just open login dialog and then keep the session?

Comment: @Kuzgun I solving an issue how to get accessToken from OAuth dialog back to the Flash that opened it. Tag token is to pair the Flash and the accessToken.

Comment: Let flash request some URL from your own server periodically. Set the OAuth Callback to some resource on your server. If the callback is called, change the output of the resource flash is polling, and you're done. Sure, polling isn't the best thing to do, but I see no way round this here. SO yes, you'Re right: just redirect everytihng over your server. BUt make sure you use soe sort of authentication between flash and yourself, too. Best encryption, too. If you do so, it should be fine security-wise. Not sure about terms of conduct here, haven'T read them.

Comment: @JohannesH. I don't have problems working around the security or design of getting facebook accessToken, my question is if facebook policy allows it (or at least doesn't forbid it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The facebook platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) does not limit you from doing what you want. As long as you pass the login process through your domain (you don't have any other option) and add a "logout" link, you will be fine.